# Why do I get an exception when pulling an image from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i get image from uiimagepickerviewcontroller and set it in global file but when i try to retrieve it from global it will not display in uiimageview

following is code of delegate method form which i get image

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    UIImage *tempimg = image; 
    [Global setimage:tempimg];
    isphototeken = TRUE;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [tblsubmenu reloadData];
    NSLog(@"global image %@",[Global getimage]);
    [picker release];

}
```

error at display time

bad exception application is terminate

Comment: It's unclear why you're using a local variable (temping) here. Also, where in this does it break?

Comment: And what exception does it throw?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line.

```
NSLog(@"global image %@",[Global getimage]);
```

giving image to the log???
you just try to comment out this line and run and check whether the application runs or not

Comment: but i get image here and i pass this image to my next controller so at that  i place write this code 

imgproducttoupload.image = [Global getimage]; 

imgproducttoupload is uiimageview in next controller where i show image
here i found bad exception